# Using link variable in header function causing "too many redirect error" in php

Tags: php

I am using this code for finding whether user using mobile or desktop and redirecting user to mobile folder if user using mobile device by using  `header` function but it is causing "too many redirect error" .

```
<?php 
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$iPod = stripos($useragent, "iPod"); 
$iPad = stripos($useragent, "iPad"); 
$iPhone = stripos($useragent, "iPhone");
$Android = stripos($useragent, "Android"); 
$iOS = stripos($useragent, "iOS");
$Blackberry =stripos($useragent, "Blackberry");

$DEVICE = ($iPod||$iPad||$iPhone||$Android||$iOS||$Blackberry);

if (!$DEVICE) { 
header('Location: http://localhost/pogester/view_post.php?post_id=495');
exit();
?>

<!-- What you want for all non-mobile devices. Anything with all HTML, PHP, CSS, even full page codes-->

<?php }else{ 
//echo $useragent;
header('Location: http://localhost/pogester/mobile/view_post.php?post_id=495');
exit();
}
?>
```

**please note that the path is different for mobile device**

Answer (score 2):

Is this code you posted stored in a file called view_post.php? If so then this file redirects to itself indefinitely.

Comment: but path is different for mobile and it goes to mobile folder when user have mobile device

Comment: yes, but once you determine what kind of device the user is using, you'll enter a redirection loop to the same target eternally.

Answer (score 0):

Each time this code works you get a redirect. To avoid it you should check not only current device but current url too. Somethings like this:

```
if (!$DEVICE && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "mobile/")) { 
header('Location: http://localhost/pogester/view_post.php?post_id=495');
exit();
if ($DEVICE && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "mobile/")) { 
header('Location: http://localhost/pogester/mobile/view_post.php?post_id=495');
exit();
}
```